# How to edit NAT settings for chan_pjsip

Tags: asterisk, pjsip, freepbx

I have configured freepbx behind the router. No audio was the issue. As shown in picture, changing `NAT = yes` and `IP Configuration` to `static` in `Settings > SIP Settings >  Chan SIP Settings` solved the issue for `chain_sip` extensions. But I am also using `chan_pjsip`. I am unable to find this option for `chan_pjsip` in freepbx. How can I configure `static IP` for `chan_pjsip` extensions?

[image: NAT Settings for chan_sip]

Answer (score 0):

Nat settings for pjsip are per-entry in endpoint.